# Firebase Integration with Django REST

Tags: django, firebase, flutter

I am building a mobile application on Flutter and have integrated a Firebase login to the application. I also have a Python Django REST API that is called within the app. I am hoping to integrate Firebase with the REST API so that the users in Firebase can become authenticated users of the API (and so I can create tokens and tokenize the API endpoint).

Does anyone know of a method I can use for this? Novice programmer and new to Firebase so let me know if there is a better way to do this! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 7):

The Firebase docs explain this well, if you check out the following URL: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens .
I started a Django app to handle this myself which you can download from PyPi: drf-firebase-auth, which you can either use yourself or fork the repo and adjust as suitable to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch any of your data in JSON format by appending '.json' to the end of the URL in which your data resides and, then send an HTTPS request through your browser. Like all other REST specific APIs, Firebase offers a client to update(PATCH, PUT), create(POST), or remove(DELETE) his stored data along with just to fetch it. below the first link is a python interface to the firebase.

[Python interface to the Firebase's REST API Documentation](http://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/)

[Github Repo Python interface to the Firebase's REST API](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase)

Firebase REST Documentation
[Installation & Setup for REST API](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase)